# How to Trick Zend loader for multiple classes in one file

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception

I'm trying to implement custom exception classes for a zend project.
I use modules and all my classes are under `library`.
so a filename `DuplicateFileException.php` which is  under 
`APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Abra/Exception"` contains

```
class Abra_Exception_FileNotFoundExcpetion extends Exception {}
class Abra_Exception_MissingFileException extends Exception {}
class Abra_Exception_DuplicateFileException extends Exception {}
class Abra_Exception_FileIOException extends Exception {}
```

so the ErrorController works fine when i only throw `Abra_Exception_DuplicateFileException`
 because there is indeed a file called DuplicateFileException, but the app breaks when i throw any other than that Exception.

I just can't believe that i have to create a file for each of them.
so how to work around it?

thanks for reading.

Comment: it seem to be not really conventional. it's almost like i would be creating empty files 4 or 5 times

Comment: Which *convention* is it swaying from? Most OOP languages seem to prefer a direct class-to-file mapping

Answer (score 2):

Proper zend-way would be implementing your own autoloader class. IT will implement autoload method. You can then use Zend_Autoloader autoloader stack to oad your classes. You just need to have some kind of system/logic in your classname->filename mapping.

```
class Abra_Autoloader 
{
    public function autoload($className)
    {
        if (strpos('Abra_Exception', $className) !== false) {
            include $someFile; //faster
        }
    }
}

//anywhere in bootstrap (preferably in some autoloading section of yours)
//  autoloader will load only classes starting with "abra"
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array('Abra_Autoloader ', 'autoload'), 'Abra');
```

Please note that at least teh autoloader class should be Zend_Loader-loadable :)

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestion. you code assumes that the class Abra_Autoloader sits under `APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Abra"`.but where to put this: `$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array('Abra_Autoloader ', 'autoload'), 'Abra');`

Answer (score 1):

The Zend autoloader works by mapping requested class names to filesystem paths so you can't make it load a file for a class where the filename does not match.

If you really want to persist down this path, I'd just include the file in your Bootstrap class, eg

```
protected function _initRequires()
{
    require_once 'Abra/Exception/DuplicateFileException.php';
    // assuming your "library" folder is on the include path
}
```

Comment: Mainly because it will load them upon bootstrapping. Imagine you have something like Zend_GData (20+ classes) in one file. Including such codebase is really bad for memory consumption. It will also be required even when not needed. For simple 4-line file like in example it will do, but generaly it'S a bad practice.